# Replace a certain character contained in text part of an HTML string in Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a string which is valid HTML like

```
s = """<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

<p class="story">...</p>"""
```

I want to replace a certain character, say `a` in this string with `x`, the condition being only the `a` occuring in inner text of HTML are to be replaced, and any `a` that are part of markup tags or values should not be replaced.

I tried using BeautifulSoup and its `get_text()` method, but that doesn't solve my purpose. Is there a way I can achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BeautifulSoup to give you a list of all of the text elements within the document. For each of these you can then make use of the [`replace_with()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) function to replace the [`NavigableString`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) object with an updated version, in your case one with the necessary characters replaced:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

s = """<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

<p class="story">...</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")

for text in list(soup.strings):
    text.replace_with(NavigableString(text.replace('a', 'x')))

print(soup)
```

So replacing all `a` characters with `x` would give you:

```html
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>
<p class="story">Once upon x time there were three little sisters; xnd their nxmes were
<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lxcie</a> xnd
<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
xnd they lived xt the bottom of x well.</p>
<p class="story">...</p></body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.